# Suppose $F: V \to U$ is linear and $k$ is a nonzero scalar. Prove that the maps $F$ and $kF$ have the same kernel and the same image.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Any help starting this proof or proving the above is appreciated. I know how to prove for the kernel now but not sure about proving for the image.

I've been trying to prove for the image using the definition of the image of F and one of two conditions that make a mapping linear (that is scalar multiplication which says for any scalar k, and v (vector) is an element of V (the vector space), we have F(kv) = kF(v)).

Does anybody know any helpful definitions for proving the image?

Comment: It is an exercise in using the definitions. If $x$ is in the kernel of $F$, then $Fx = 0$. Now you have to prove that $(kF)x = 0$. What property would you use to prove this?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I used scalar multiplication to prove (kF)x = 0.

Comment: You seem to have cleaned up the kernel part. The same applies for the image : if $w$ is in the image of $F$, then there is some $v$ such that $w = Fv$, but then $w = (kF)\left(\frac 1k v\right)$, so $w$ is also in the image of $kF$. A similar argument will do it backwards